# php: Cron error, Connection refused

Tags: php, cron, plesk, port80

I try to do a cron job via Plesk with the command line:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://sd-xxxxx.dedibox.fr/action
```

and I get the following error:

```
Connecting to sd-xxxxx.dedibox.fr (sd-xxxxx.dedibox.fr)|127.0.1.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

idem with `curl http://sd-xxxxx.dedibox.fr/action`

(the url is accessible via browser without any identification)

I have two server and the first work perfectly with this command, Any thoughts?
thank

Answer (score 0):

May be mod_sec is blocking your access, Can you please check your doamin error logs and let me know what error are you getting in logs file.